# Scraping online store and writing to database

Tags: python, object-oriented, design-patterns

I'm making a project that will scrape some online store for an item, gets the data and stores it in a remote database that I have, and also able to read the database and display the data on a dashboard that uses Flask. It roughly works now, but I'd appreciate some inputs on how to make the design better, since I'm a beginner in this. I tried to implement SOLID ideas as much as possible, but not sure if I'm doing it right.

The class with common worker functions:

```
import getopt, sys, time, json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from sqlalchemy import inspect, create_engine, Column, String, Integer
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm.scoping import scoped_session
from sqlalchemy.orm.session import sessionmaker
import sshtunnel
from flask import request, Flask
import pandas as pd
import re, os
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
import platform, importlib
from customExceptions import *
from interruptingcow import timeout
import subprocess

day = str(time.localtime().tm_mday)
month =  str(time.localtime().tm_mon)
year = str(time.localtime().tm_year)
hour = str(time.localtime().tm_hour) if len(str(time.localtime().tm_hour)) >= 2 else "0" + str(time.localtime().tm_hour)
minute = str(time.localtime().tm_min) if len(str(time.localtime().tm_min)) >= 2 else "0" + str(time.localtime().tm_min)

class SSHTunnelOperations:
    def __init__(self,username,password,dialect,schema):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.dialect = dialect
        self.schema = schema

    def getURI(self):
        print(f"Obtaining URI to be able to write and read from database...")
        sqlalchemy_database_uri = f'{self.dialect}://{self.username}:{self.password}@127.0.0.1:\
                                    {self._tunnelToDatabaseServer().local_bind_port}/{self.username}${self.schema}'
        return sqlalchemy_database_uri

    def _tunnelToDatabaseServer(self):
        tunnel = sshtunnel.SSHTunnelForwarder(
            ('ssh.pythonanywhere.com'),
            ssh_username=self.username,
            ssh_password=self.password,
            local_bind_address=("127.0.0.1",3306),
            remote_bind_address=('myusername.mysql.pythonanywhere-services.com', 3306)
        )
        # Start SSH tunneling
        print("Connecting to ssh.pythonanywhere.com database using SSH tunneling")
        print("Starting tunnel...")
        tunnel.start()
        print("Tunnel started")
        return tunnel

class DBoperations(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def read_from_db(self,store):
        pass
    @abstractmethod
    def write_to_db(self,store,searchterm,itemPriceLink):
        pass

class DBOperationsFlask(DBoperations):
    def __init__(self,db):
        self.db = db
            
    def read_from_db(self,store):
        store = "".join(store)
        print("reading data from " + store + "...")
        # Create class of each db dynamically
        self.db.metadata.clear()
        @classmethod
        def overridePrint(self):
            return '{} {} {} {} {}'.format(self.id, self.searchTerm, self.date, self.item, self.price)
        # Use locals since database variable is local for read_from_db only
        locals()[store] = type(store,(self.db.Model,),{
            "id" : self.db.Column(self.db.Integer, primary_key=True),
            "searchTerm": self.db.Column(self.db.String(100), unique=False),
            "date" : self.db.Column(self.db.String(100), unique=False),
            "item" : self.db.Column(self.db.String(100), unique=False),
            "price" :  self.db.Column(self.db.String(100), unique=False),
            "link" : self.db.Column(self.db.String(255), unique = False),
            "__repr__": overridePrint,
        })
        
        session=self.db.session()
        sqlQuery = session.query(eval(store)).statement
        sessionEngine = eval(store).query.session.bind
        data = pd.read_sql(sqlQuery, sessionEngine)
        print("reading complete!")
        return data

    def write_to_db():
        # Don't forget to make this later otherwise we break Interface Segregation principle
        pass

class interrogateStoreFlask(DBOperationsFlask):
    def available_online_stores(self):
        availableStores = inspect(self.db.engine).get_table_names()
        return availableStores
    
class DBOperationsRaw(DBoperations):
    def __init__(self,username,password,dialect,schema):
        self.sqlalchemy_database_uri = SSHTunnelOperations(username,password,dialect,schema).getURI()
        self.Base = declarative_base()
        self.engine = create_engine(self.sqlalchemy_database_uri)
        self.Base.metadata.create_all(self.engine)
        Session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(self.engine))
        self.session = Session()
    
    def read_from_db():
        # Don't forget to make this later otherwise we break Interface Segregation principle
        pass

    def write_to_db(self,store,searchterm,itemPriceLink):
        dateScraped = day + "/" + month + "/" + year + " " + hour + ":" + minute
        @classmethod
        def overridePrint(self):
            return '{} {} {} {} {}'.format(self.id, self.searchTerm, self.date, self.item, self.price)
        # Use locals since database variable is local for write_to_db only
        locals()[store] = type(store,(self.Base,),{
            "__tablename__": store,
            "id" : Column(Integer, primary_key=True),
            "searchTerm": Column(String(255), unique=False),
            "date" : Column(String(100), unique=False),
            "item" : Column(String(255), unique=False),
            "price" :  Column(String(100), unique=False),
            "link" : Column(String(255), unique = False),
            "__repr__": overridePrint
        })
        for itemScraped, priceScraped, itemLink in itemPriceLink:
            current = eval(store)(date=dateScraped,searchTerm=searchterm,
                                     item=itemScraped,price=priceScraped,link=itemLink)
            self.session.add(current)
        try:
            print("write successful")
            self.session.commit()
        except Exception:
            print("write failed")
            self.session.rollback()
        finally:
            self.session.close()
    
class Scrape():
    def __init__(self,storeName,searchTerm,extract_record):
        self.extract_record = extract_record
        self.storeName = storeName
        self.searchTerm = searchTerm

        self.OnServer = True if "OnServer" in os.environ else False
        self.geckodriverExe = r"/geckodriver" if platform.system() == 'Linux' else r"/geckodriver.exe"
        self.itemPriceLink = []

        try:
            getattr(sys.modules[__name__], self.storeName + "URL")
        except AttributeError:
            raise StoreNotSupportedException

        self.pwd = os.path.dirname(__file__).replace(os.sep, '/')

        self.searchTerm = self.searchTerm.upper()

        self.firefox_options = Options()
        self.firefox_options.add_argument("--headless")

        try:
            print(f"Attempt {attempt + 1} of activating geckodriver")
            self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=self.pwd + self.geckodriverExe, options=self.firefox_options)
            print("geckodriver successfully activated")
            break
        except Exception:
            subprocess.run(['pkill', '-f', 'firefox'])
            raise DriverException

    # Scrapes store and updates self.itemPriceLink
    def scrapeStore(self):
        try:
            print("Scraping...")
            for page in range(1,2):
                self.driver.get(self._get_url(page))
                self.soup = BeautifulSoup(self.driver.page_source)
                self.extract_record(self.searchTerm,self.soup,self.itemPriceLink,self.storeName)
            return self.itemPriceLink
        except Exception:
            raise ErrorDuringScrapingException
        finally:
            self.driver.close()
            subprocess.run(['pkill', '-f', 'firefox'])

    def _get_url(self, page):
        searchTermForURL=self.searchTerm.replace(" ","+")
        url = getattr(sys.modules[__name__], self.storeName + "URL")().URL_by_page_and_item(searchTermForURL,page)
        return url

# I do the following to implement open for extension closed for modification, so I can add new stores easily later
class storeURL(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def URL_by_page_and_item(self,searchTerm,page):
        pass
class bolURL(storeURL):
    def URL_by_page_and_item(self,searchTerm,page):
        return "https://www.bol.com/nl/nl/s/?page={}&searchtext={}&view=list".format(page,searchTerm)
class coolblueURL(storeURL):
    def URL_by_page_and_item(self,searchTerm,page):
        return "https://www.coolblue.nl/zoeken?query={}&page={}".format(searchTerm,page)
class amazonURL(storeURL):
    def URL_by_page_and_item(self,searchTerm,page):
        return "https://www.amazon.nl/s?k={}&page={}".format(searchTerm,page)
```

One file that uses the functions to scrape and write to database:

```
from webScraperCommon import Scrape, DBOperationsRaw
from inputProcessor import getSearchTermFromInput
from customExceptions import *
import re

def extract_record(searchTerm,soup,itemPriceLink,storeName):
    divItemPrice = soup.find_all('div',['product-card__details'])

    for div in divItemPrice:
        try:
            fullTitle = [child.get("title") for child in div.findChildren("a") if child.has_attr("title")][0]
            fullPrice = [child.text for child in div.findChildren("strong") \
                        if child.get("class",default = ["False"])[0] == "sales-price__current"][0]
            link = [storeName + ".nl" +child.get("href") 
                    for child in div.findChildren("a") 
                    if child.has_attr("href")][0]
            if re.search(searchTerm, fullTitle, re.IGNORECASE):
                itemPriceLink.append((fullTitle,fullPrice,link))
        except Exception:
            raise("Exception in extract_record function; website may have changed their structure :(")

def main():
    try:
        storeName = re.search(r"\w+(?=Scraper.py)",__file__).group(0)
    except AttributeError:
        raise InvalidFilenameException
    searchTerm = getSearchTermFromInput()

    print(f"Scraping {storeName} for {searchTerm}")
    
    scrapeFunction = Scrape(storeName,searchTerm,extract_record)
    scrapingResult = scrapeFunction.scrapeStore()
    try:
        assert scrapingResult != []
    except AssertionError:
        raise EmptyResultException(storeName)
    DBfunction = DBOperationsRaw(username="myusername",password="mypassword",dialect="mysql",schema="dateItemPrice")
    DBfunction.write_to_db(storeName,searchTerm,scrapingResult)
    
if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

And the file is supposed to be run like:
`python amazonScraper.py Sony XM3210`

The custom exceptions are in another file, and I'm not worried about it's design.

Some of my doubts:

1. How can I incorporate helper functions (like _get_url) into the design correctly? Yes I can make another class, but it feels very unnecessary and I end up with a lot of classes. If someone imports the module, they then see this helper that I would like to hide from them. Maybe in general, how can I make hidden classes that can only be imported by classes in that module?
2. The webdriver.Firefox() function, which instantiates the driver, hangs sometimes. I'd like to make a retry if it hangs after a determined period of time (i.e. a timeout). How can I best do this? I have looked into libraries that do this, but they only work in Linux since they use SIGKILL to implement the timeout, which is not supported in Windows. I'd like to make my code implementable in all OS. If possible a solution that incorporates use of decorators, since I'd like to learn that topic too?
3. I'm using eval() in DBOperationsRaw class in write_to_db function. I know it's a bad practice, how can I avoid this?
4. I am using `except Exception` all the time, is this acceptable or should I use `BaseException` instead?

And any other inputs would be much appreciated. Thank you.